# Is there a way to string.format a runtime-determined number of items in one call in Chapel?

Tags: chapel

Is there a way to use one `string.format()` call to format a runtime-determined number of items?

I wrote a program that generates a million md5sums and converts them to string with

```
  md5.getDigest(input).toHexString();
```

It took 3 minutes on my laptop, but only 50 seconds if I modify the `Crypto` package's `toHexString()` as follows to use fewer seperate `.format()` calls to generate the string (I'm assuming due to the string append for each one).  I take this to mean formatting the string takes at least twice as long as generating the md5sum in the first place.

```
@ -239,9 +239,17 @@ module Crypto {
     */
     proc toHexString() throws {
       var buffHexString: string;
-      for i in this.buffDomain do {
+      var next = this.buffDomain.first;
+      for i in this.buffDomain by 8 do
+       if this.buffDomain.contains(i+7) {
+         buffHexString += try ("%02xu"*8).format(
+               this.buff[i+0], this.buff[i+1], this.buff[i+2], this.buff[i+3],
+               this.buff[i+4], this.buff[i+5], this.buff[i+6], this.buff[i+7]);
+         next = i+8;
+       }
+      for i in this.buffDomain[next..] do
         buffHexString += try "%02xu".format(this.buff[i]);
-      }
+
       return buffHexString;
     }
   }
```

but that's gross.  I'd like to do something like

```
bufHexString = try ("%02xu" * this.buff.size).format(this.buff .... something);
```

but `string.format()` only accepts its var args by `args ...?k` which needs a compile-time param number of args.

The question I'm asking is about getting `string.format` to work like this, but I'd also be happy with another way to generate a string like this all at once without any intermediate temporary strings.  (I don't see a way to do it in Chapel code via the `string.createBorrowingBuffer()` without dropping into `c_ptr`s.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this post points out something missing from the `string` and `bytes` types. What is missing is the ability to append a codepoint (as an `int(32)`) or a byte (as a `uint(8)`). I will look at adding these to Chapel's standard library.

But, I will answer your question more directly. It turns out that `string.format` actually operates through the IO system. That is how the format strings match with `writef` -- it is actually using the same implementation. `string.format` does this with `openMemFile`. But you can do the same thing, e.g.:

```
use IO;
var f = openMemFile();
{
  var w = f.writer(locking=false);
  for byte in A {
    w.writef("%02xu", byte);
  }
}
var r = f.reader(locking=false);
return r.readAll(string);
```

In some quick performance experiments in this area, I observed on my system (with running `toHex` on a 16-element array of `uint(8)`):

- about 40k toHex calls/second with the original implementation
- about 460k toHex calls/second with this `openMemFile` approach
- about 550k toHex calls/second with

  ```
   ("%02xu"*16).format(
         A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3],
         A[4], A[5], A[6], A[7],
         A[8], A[9], A[10], A[11],
         A[12], A[13], A[14], A[15]);
  ```

But, even better performance is available with the ability to append a numeric byte value / codpoint value:

- about 9000k toHex calls/second using draft code to append an integral byte/codepoint value
- about 17000k toHex calls/second using draft code to append a tuple of integral byte/codepoint values